# How to align buttons based on phone screen in a GridLayout?

Tags: java, android

So I have a `ScrollView` inside of a `GridLayout` and I'm trying to change it so that the buttons will resize based off the size of the phone, but so far I can't get a button to appear.  I have a set height and a width of 0 as a style for each `ImageView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowOrderPreserved="false"
    grid:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
        android:id="@+id/bucksImageView"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        />

    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView


        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
        android:id="@+id/heatImageView"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true"
        style="@style/buttonStyle" />

    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView


        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"

        android:id="@+id/hawksImageView"

        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:gravity="center"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true"
        style="@style/buttonStyle" />
```